# Multiplication and Division of Summations

Tags: reference-request, summation

Could you please discuss or provide an online reference/tutorial which teaches how to do division (or multiplication) of summations? For example in this [post](https://mathhelpforum.com/threads/summation-division.212491/) there is a question about the same issue, but I don't understand it. Here is an example:

$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i $ divide by (or multiply by)$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} x{_i}{^2}$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: cf. [discrete convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution)

Answer (score 1):

The final answer on the page you link is correct (for division).  It doesn't simplify.  Just think about the $n=2$ case.  You'd have $$\frac{x+y}{x^2+y^2}.$$  For multiplication, you can write 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nx_ix_j^2$$ but personally, I think the first first form is "simpler."